# Get the page protection of a user mode page from kernel mode

Tags: windows, kernel, wdk

I want to get the page protection of a user-mode page from user kernel-mode.
I know it's possible using the undocumented function NtQueryVirtualMemory (which is the way that windows XP uses when VirtualQuery is called in user mode)

But I rather do it in some documented way...

If it's Possible to traverse the VAD list in a documented way it will be great as well, because it will allow me to check the page protection of a lot of pages quickly.

Comment: Try ZwQueryVirtualMemory. Documented on MSDN.